# Django apache2, & wsgi without vitrualenv (global installation)

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, python, django, mod-wsgi

I'm running django app globally on Ubuntu server running apache2. Below is my configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog /root/apache2_logs/error.log
        CustomLog /root/apache2_logs/access.log combined

         <Directory /root/scryer/scryer_project/>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

         WSGIDaemonProcess scryer python-home=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages python-path=/root/scryer
         WSGIProcessGroup scryer
         WSGIScriptAlias / /root/scryer/scryer_project/wsgi.py

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

</VirtualHost>
```

everything seems fine but I'm getting the:
"Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource" error.

More details:
AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/root/scryer') because search permissions are missing.

I've spent many hours on this issue and seems to persist.  What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much.